# trouble Replacing outliers with Median in python

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, outliers

```py
for col in ('DiabetesPedigreeFunction','Insulin'):
    Q1=df[col].quantile(0.25)
    Q3=df[col].quantile(0.75)

    IQR=Q3-Q1

    upper_limit= Q3+1.5*IQR
    lower_limit= Q1-1.5*IQR

    db_median= float(df[col].median())
    In_median= float(df[col].median())

    df[col]=np.where(df[col]>upper_limit,db_median,df[col])
    df[col]=np.where(df[col]>upper_limit,In_median,df[col])
```

The code runs well, however, using boxplot to check... the outliers are still there, also using `.describe()`... outliers are still noted.

Any Help pls

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P9bu.png)
After using code posted

```py
>>> list_cols = ['DiabetesPedigreeFunction','Insulin']
>>> df[list_cols] = np.where(((df[list_cols] - df[list_cols].mean()) /     df[list_cols].std()).abs() >= 3, df[list_cols].median(), df[list_cols])
```

The results remain similar to my previous code...view image

```py
>>> df["DiabetesPedigreeFunction"].describe()
count    768.000000
mean       0.449800
std        0.279715
min        0.078000
25%        0.243750
50%        0.371750
75%        0.602000
max        1.461000
Name: DiabetesPedigreeFunction, dtype: float64
```

Comment: ok...here's the link https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database

Comment: The data needed to be cleaned due to the fact that some variables were riddled with zeros (0's). e.g Insulin, BMI of patient can't be zero, so it had to be replaced by Nan then mean/median using " .replace" function... Then we get to the part of how skewed the data is..which in fact riddled with Outliers.